# Two Gas Lines Running into House

Tags: gas, natural-gas

I seem to have an old underground gas pipe coming into my basement which seems to still have gas in the line, however it is not connected to my meter. I am currently digging out my mud room (on the other side of the wall in the attached photo) and would like to remove this old line.

Firstly, why would there be two lines? (both with gas in)

Secondly, who’s responsibility is the 2nd pipe which seems not to go to the meter, and runs under ground.

I’ve search around the web and can’t find anyone with this problem.

I hope someone out there may have advise. Thaks.

[image]

Comment: Well I would call the gas company , but a person that had questionable morals would connect to it.

Comment: Are you in a single family home or a connected structure?

Comment: Are you sure it’s inbound?  Perhaps it fed something outdoors that’s not there anymore like a gas light or gas grill.  Maybe it’s just capped somewhere, or maybe it still feeds an outdoor appliance or light currently and you just haven’t realized it’s function yet.